# Is my conversion of this sentence into a formal statement correct?

Tags: logic

Write the following in symbolic form: 'You'll love swimming if you have nice strokes, and you'll be able to pull tricks'

Let p = 'You'll love swimming' q = ' You have nice strokes' r = 'you'll be able to pull tricks'

ANS: $(p \implies q) \wedge r$ [correct]?

Answer (score 1):

$(q \implies p) \wedge r$ would be more accurate, as if you have nice strokes, then you will love swimming, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually $q \implies (p \wedge r)$, since having nice strokes is a condition to pull tricks